# Regexp for searching java code in text

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to find all java code in string. String may contain any text. This my regexp, but when I run program, it work for a long time and not stop

```
private static final String PATTERN_CODE = "[^;,\\{\\}]+\\s+[^;,{}]+\\s*\\{.*?\\}";
```

I try to find some examples of this regexp, but I found nothing(

Comment: What do you consider 'java code' within a string of arbitrary text? Every substring that forms a complete valid Java program? Or every substring that may (depending on context) validly appear within a Java program? If the latter, are substrings which are valid within a Java string literal also 'java code'?

Comment: For example, I have some ebook about Java programming, it have text and code examples. So I need to split code and text.

Comment: You're probably over-engineering this. You'll learn more from your book if you read it and copy-paste fragments to try out as you go along. And you'll learn yet more, if you type the fragments in yourself, try them, then try your own variations of them and try to predict what they'll do when you change them.

Comment: Distinguishing Java code from English prose is probably impossible in general. Depending on the source you might be more lucky to extract code based on (semantic or physical) markup/formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find a java code inside a strinh with a regular expression, you must take into account variable declaration/initialization, inner classes, etc.

You need a parser.

You can use [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) and a [java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) (there are two version available java7 and java8) to detect if a string contains a valid Java fragment. You can write a custom `ErrorListener` to define how to handle invalid java fragments.

**UPDATE**

Here ia sample program that throws a RuntimeException if the String in input is not a valid java program:

```
package test.parsingjava;

import java.io.StringReader;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

import test.schyntax.parsing.ErrorListener;

public class ParsingJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String expression="class test { public void method() {}}";
        StringReader reader= new StringReader(expression);
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(reader);
        JavaLexer lexer= new JavaLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        JavaParser parser= new JavaParser(tokens);
        parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener
        parser.addErrorListener(new ErrorListener());
        ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); 
        // Walk the tree created during the parse, trigger callbacks 
        JavaListener listener=new JavaBaseListener();
        walker.walk(listener, tree);
    }

}
```

the ErrorListener is:

```
package test.parsingjava;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Recognizer;

public class ErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {
    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error at line " + line + ":" + charPositionInLine + " at " + offendingSymbol + ": " + msg);
    }
}
```

the other classes are generate from the command line using

```
antlr4 -package test.parsingjava Java.g4
```

antlr4 is a script that runs antrl4.jar from the command line and Java.g4 can be found [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4)

Comment: Oh, thanks.
Can you write some example of searching java code in string with using ANTLR? It wiil be very helpful

Comment: @OranGE done, example with source code added